# How to find all instances of a character in a list without using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In my python project I need to make a list of all matches of a specific character within a string, for example: `A -> ABHAXA -> [0,3,5]`

I know that a solution like this would work:
    `indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "whatever"]`

But the problem is that, in order to fulfill a requirement of this project, I can't use for loops in any way. Is there a good way to do this using filter, map, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: use a while loop

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: A while loop would work technically, and it could be done multiple ways.  Is that considered a type of `for` loop?

Comment: Good point, I think all loops (including while) are not allowed, neither are any packages like numpy.

Comment: you have a project in which you cannot use loops? Sounds like school homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
s = 'ABHAXA'
c = 'A'

filter(lambda i: c == s[i], range(len(s)))
```

Comment: of course, but it sounds like the point (contrived IMO) is not use the key word `for`. I don't see how there could be any solution not using implicit loop under the hood...